# how to call another process from a c# project?

Tags: c#, wpf, serial-port

Is it possible to call some process(or exe) from the main program, send it some parameters, get some processing done and return back the result? If possible, which is the best way to do that?

I have a wpf application for managing mills. This application is used in different mills. The only difference is that the serial port communication for weighing used in the mills are different. Currently the weighing section is programmed into the application. But this makes difficult to maintain, as i have to have different versions of the project dependng on the weighbridge. So I want it like this : I have single version of the main project. The main project calls another process (or exe) and sends in some parameters. This exe does the weighing and sends back the weights. [image]

Comment: Use a library project (DLL) instead.

Comment: Did you write the second process ?

Comment: @Micah Armantrout: No, just wondering whether I should create a separate exe or create a library project as suggested by SLaks

Comment: @sony This is practically the textbook definition of what a library is for.

Comment: @sony: I suggest creating a library project, which will split out a DLL. You can then call methods on the DLL by adding it as a reference to your main project. You want to re use your code as much as possible. Example: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s16p1.html

Comment: These comments need to be answers.

Comment: @JordanParmer Comments are great places for speculative answers, especially when the question isn't clear. People don't want to risk being downvoted when the user clarifies their question and now the answer is wrong or not relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if all you have is another exe file then you can run it using (taken from http://www.dotnetperls.com/process-start)

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.FileName = "dcm2jpg.exe";
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.Arguments = "-f j -o \"" + ex1 + "\" -z 1.0 -s y " + ex2;

try
{
        // Start the process with the info we specified.
        // Call WaitForExit and then the using statement will close.
        using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
        {
           exeProcess.WaitForExit();
        }   
}
catch
{
    // Log error.
}
```